# Observer in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am new at angular and I am confused with the behaviour of the rxjs observable.
Let me show you a simple example and so that you can understand my question.

```
test = new Observable((observer)=>{
    console.log(observer);
    observer.next(1);

     });
this.subscription = this.test.subscribe((result)=>{
        console.log(1);
     });
```

When I printed the observer I saw no next property directly inside the object rather next was inside a nested object name "destination".
  Now can anyone explain me what is actually happening inside?How the call back passing inside subscribe operator is getting invoked? Thank you in advance.

Comment: My guess is its part of the prototype(probably in your debugger its called _proto_ or something similar). You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: I completely misread your question at first. The parameter you call `observer` is a subscriber http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscriber.js~Subscriber.html

Answer (score 1):

The property is not attached to the object itself, but rather on its prototype.

You can have a look at the code yourself by importing

```
import {Subscriber} from 'rxjs/Subscriber.js'
```

and using your IDE to navigate to the class definition.

---

[Official docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscriber.js~Subscriber.html)